# Using bootstrap-slider and bootstrap-switch in wordpress admin panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-switch, bootstrap-slider

I'm creating a Wordpress theme with an admin panel and I would like to put bootstrap switch and bootstrap sliders like:

[image]
OR
[image]

But the problem is that I find the scripts in the page correctly added but nothing happen. I have the scripts enqueued like this:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts');
function load_admin_scripts( $hook ){

if($hook == 'toplevel_page_boon_theme'){
        //Slider
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider/bootstrap-slider.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

    }
}
```

In the files of the page I find correctly this scripts but when I try to slide nothing happens.

I have the input like this:

```
<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
```

And in the javascript I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Slider Bootstrap header
    $("#ex6").slider();
});
```

It creates inside the input a span like this:

[image]

But the input that I show is an usual input:
[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I know it can be possible because I have shown in another themes.

Thanks a million for the help.

Comment: bootstrap-slider.min.css not included properly. Please bootstrap-slider.min.css file included in your page

Comment: Why is not included properly? I saw in the page files @vel

Comment: what is the error on console?

Comment: remove this condtion and check if($hook == 'toplevel_page_boon_theme').

Comment: There is no error in console, it's that the slider doesn't appear. I don't want to remove this line because if I remove it all the scripts are included in all pages and it is not fine. The other scripts are added correctly like this one but the problem is that is not working the javascript because the slider or the switch don't appear

Comment: add boostrap css in this hook function adminfooter() {    
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'adminfooter');. you can remove later.

Comment: @vel it doesn't work. Now the css is not in the head of the page. In the other way it is there.

Comment: This is works for me

if($_GET['page']=='your_page'){
 wp_enqueue_style("boostrap", $themeurl."/css/responsive-tabs.css", false);
}

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/add-header-and-footer-to-wp-backend